# How to UNION ALL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to check list of points inside list of multipolygon. I tried to check all point around 9952 points  but i have problem. The problem is the record don't want to show, but if i limit the query, it showing.
I want to try to merge queries using UNION ALL.

Query to check all Points

```
with p as (
    select multipolygon from public.regional
)SELECT * FROM  p,final_results_all_operators
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(p.multipolygon), public.final_results_all_operators.point)
```

Query with UNION ALL -- Still error

```
with p as (
    select multipolygon from public.regional
)SELECT * FROM  p,final_results_all_operators
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(p.multipolygon), public.final_results_all_operators.point)
limit 5000
UNION ALL
with c as (
    select multipolygon from public.regional
)SELECT * FROM  c,final_results_all_operators
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(c.multipolygon), public.final_results_all_operators.point)
limit 4952 offset 5000;
```

Comment: Can you also provide some sample data? Optionally with insert statements or inside a fiddle. Additionally a create table statement - containing indexes - would also help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `OFFSET`, `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY` clauses in the queries, you have to use parentheses to not confuse the parser:

```
(SELECT ...
 LIMIT 500)
UNION
(SELECT ...
 LIMIT 500);
```